# Split large flat file into multiple files with groupby particular field and store diff group of 500 records in diff files

Tags: java-8, apache-camel

I have a large flat file like

```
Name Id
Abc 123
Fgg 345
Ghj 123
Vhg 456
Fhh 678
Hjj 345
Hjf 456
Ijk 789
```

For ex, I want to split above file into multiple flat files based on groupby Id and each file should contain only 2 groups of records I.etle

file1

```
Abc 123
Ghj 123
Fgg 345
Hjj 345
```

file2

```
Vhg 456
Hjf 456
Fhh 678
```

file3

```
Ijk 789
```

And I need to send all above split files to camel file component

I am able to group records based on id using java8 but unable to store particular count of groups to diff files